# Docker build and run very slow

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-18.04

I use docker on Ubuntu bionic.
`docker build` and `docker run` commands work super slow. It takes few minutes to run a container and few minutes to process each `RUN` command in dockerfile during building it.
Other docker-cli commands work good.

What can be the reason for such a behavior?

Versions of packages:

- containerd.io - 1.6.20-1_arm64
- docker-ce - 24.0.2-1~ubuntu.18.04~bionic_arm64
- docker-ce-cli - 24.0.2-1~ubuntu.18.04~bionic_arm64

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the logs that get generated when the commands are running.   That will tell you docker is doing, and should help to understand what's going on.

Comment: If you are talking about command line output - it is ok. It prints nothing during the freeze.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons why the docker build and docker run commands are running slowly on your Ubuntu system.

**1.**Resource Constraints:**** Check if your system has sufficient resources (CPU, memory, and disk space) available for running Docker containers. Insufficient resources can lead to slower performance during container execution and building.

**2.**Network Connectivity:**** Slow network connectivity or DNS resolution issues can impact the performance of pulling Docker images or accessing external resources during container execution. Verify that your network connection is stable and there are no network-related issues.
Docker often needs to download images, packages, and dependencies from external repositories, which requires a reliable and fast network connection.